# Why my text is always located on the top of screen not center?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I have a simple layout like below (which only shows a text "TEST"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
>    
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
    >

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TEST"
            android:textColor="#0099cc"
        />


    </LinearLayout>    


</LinearLayout>
```

I suppose with this layout, my text "TEST" should be located in the **middle** of the screen. But the text "TEST" is located on the top of the screen. Why?

I used `layout_gravity` and `gravity` with value ***center***, why my "TEST" text located on the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `android:gravity="center"` in your main layout

Answer (score 1):

just try it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
>    
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
    >

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TEST"
            android:textColor="#0099cc"
        />


    </LinearLayout>    


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi leem android:gravity consult with the content of specific view that means your  android:gravity="middle" place the text middle of text view not a middle of screen. your layout_gravity define the where should your view is going to be place? mean you have to set android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" of textview to view your text middle of screen

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.. In the first linear layout section of your xml file. Just add android:gravity="center" and it will work..